# Does a winforms event handler happen on the same thread as the caller?

Tags: winforms, events

Simple question, though no one at the office seems to know and I can't find a good way to ask google this. In winforms, if you have a function that handles an event (in this case, on a focusLost), does that function happen on the same thread as the one that fired the event?

So if I have a textbox with focus, which is currently running on the UI thread, and I change focus, will the UI thread then run my function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the UI thread will execute UI event handlers.

Generally, in Windows programming, you shouldn't be touching UI components on other threads. Windows Forms is designed to work via a single thread. If you need to heavy lifting that otherwise may freeze the UI thread, you spawn a new thread to do the work, then push the changes to the UI thread.

You can use [SynchronizationContext.Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.current.aspx) to post work to the UI thread. [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) is handy for this as well.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that is correct.  Normally events are handled on the GUI thread.  Here is a link below on how to do so in a different thread.

http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/526484-handling-control-ui-events-worker-threads